# The archive commoms-io-2.4.jar doesn't exist

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build.xml

```
<target name="-post-jar" depends="git.revision">
    <jar jarfile="dist/conch-latest.jar">  <!-- Line 92 -->
        <zipfileset src="${dist.jar}" excludes="META-INF/*" />  
        <zipfileset src="dist/lib/commoms-io-2.4.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
        <zipfileset src="dist/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar" excludes="META-INF/*" />
    </jar>
</target>
```

My intention is to package the Apache libraries I used in my code with my distributable jar file to make it easier to execute and include my code as a library without having to include the Apache libraries separately. However, when I get to that portion of the build.xml, I'm greeted with the following:

```
C:\Users\Axoren\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ConCh\build.xml:92: The archive commoms-io-2.4.jar doesn't exist
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Bewildered, I investigated. It's there, alright.

```
 Directory of C:\Users\Axoren\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ConCh\dist\lib

07/30/2013  02:35 AM    <DIR>          .
07/30/2013  02:35 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/30/2013  02:35 AM           214,274 commons-cli-1.2-javadoc.jar
07/30/2013  02:35 AM            48,726 commons-cli-1.2-sources.jar
07/30/2013  02:35 AM            41,123 commons-cli-1.2.jar
07/30/2013  02:35 AM           724,124 commons-io-2.4-javadoc.jar
07/30/2013  02:35 AM           246,635 commons-io-2.4-sources.jar
07/30/2013  02:35 AM           185,140 commons-io-2.4.jar
               6 File(s)      1,460,022 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  360,198,926,336 bytes free
```

So, somehow I'm doing this wrong. But I've done this before with other libraries in the exact same manner. The only difference is that this is the first time I've done it with libraries from Apache. I'd like to make this work somehow, but I'm a total novice when it comes to Ant and I can't even begin to think of what could possibly be causing Ant to fail to locate a jar file that's clearly where I said it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.

CommoMs vs. CommoNs.

Comment: ... How many bullets can I shoot my foot with before it becomes life-threatening? This is almost as bad as the I vs. J typo I often make.